# How to call function from a control using object oriented javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var objParent = new Parent();//initializing object 
function Parent() {
this.Child = function () {
     var checkBox="";
     checkBox +="<input type=\"checkbox\" 
                        name=\"ctlName\"   
                        id=\'" + cltId + "\' 
                        onchange= 'this.SubChild(this.id)'
                 />";

     $('#liCheckbox').append(checkBox);
}



this.Child.prototype = {
    SubChild: function (id) {//this function not able to access
        alert(this.first + ' ' + this.last+ ' '+id);
    }
};


}

<ul>

    <li id='liCheckbox'>

</li>
</ul>
```

I m using object oreiented javascript for developing my application.
In the above code i m calling `SubChild(this.id)` function i m calling in the checkbox change event.
But i m not able to access the function.
please suggest me if any other solution is there.

**Edited**

I got the answer

```
var objParent = new Parent();//initializing object 
function Parent() {
this.Child = function () {
     var checkBox="";
     checkBox +="<input type=\"checkbox\" 
                        name=\"ctlName\"   
                        id=\'" + cltId + "\' 
                        onchange= 'objParent.SubChild(this.id)'//While calling the we have to call with object 
                 />";

     $('#liCheckbox').append(checkBox);
}



this.Child.prototype = {
    SubChild: function (id) {//this function not able to access
        alert(this.first + ' ' + this.last+ ' '+id);
    }
};


}

<ul>

    <li id='liCheckbox'>

</li>
</ul>
```

while calling the function we have call with the object created for the class.
objParent.SubChild(this.id).

Comment: where would `this.id` come from? what id do you want to pass?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onchange` handler you have `this.SubChild(this.id)`, where `this` refers to the `input`. And since the `Child` constructor is never called (or at least I don't see it anywhere) no object will have `SubChild` method.
To have access to either an instance of `Child` or `Parent` you should use proper event binding with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` in IE8 and earlier, or use jQuery's event binding, if you have to use jQuery already. In that case you can specify what the this would be in the callback using jQuery's `proxy` function or the `bind` method of every function in newer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a lot of thing here (JS, HTML injection, event handling)...

Here's how you should do it (not tested):

```
function Parent() {
   var parent = this;

   this.Child = function () {
      var checkBox = $('<input type="checkbox" name="ctlName" id="' + cltId + '" />');
      checkBox.on('change', function() {
          parent.Child.SubChild(this.id);
      });
      $('#liCheckbox').append(checkBox);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it :

```
function Child() {
        this.name = 'test';
}
Child.prototype = {
    SubChild: function () {
            alert(this.name);
    }
}

function Parent() {
    this.child = new Child();


};

new Parent().child.SubChild();
```

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/VrrM5/